# Definitive list of Nominatim types and categories?

Tags: openstreetmap, nominatim

Is there a definitive list somewhere on the interwebs of the `category` and `type` values in **Nominatim**?

I've been doing some Googling but found nothing as yet.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a reasonable question since the official documentation is very sparse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find any `category` in the response, did you mean `class` instead?

`class` and `type` seem to be equivalent to `key` and `value` of a [tag](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags). So I *guess* the list you are searching for is located under [settings/partitionedtags.def](https://github.com/openstreetmap/Nominatim/blob/80df4d3b560f5b1fd550dcf8cdc09a992b69fee0/settings/partitionedtags.def).

Comment: Yes, that's list I was looking for!

Comment: When receiving jsonv2 response the `category` field is returned

Comment: The link is dead. Do you know where to find it today?

Comment: The link has been updated by @StevenWolfe. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Despite the post was already some years ago, I would like to add that the information is available in the following wiki page.

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_features